# Help to identify origin/history of a statuette of the Buddha?

Tags: history, statue

Can anyone help me identify this please? I can not find one the same, and would love a bit of history on him.

Small buddha bought on eBay -- stated "possibly from China", he was not sure

[image]

I'm looking to try and age or authenticate my Buddha. This is on bottom -- again I can not find one the same, only full circle ones.

[image]

Any ideas? Any help appreciated greatly in my search of his history.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the way the robe is set, It does not look like a Mahayana Buddha's statue. It seems it is Theravada Buddha. It is possible from Sri Lanka or Myanmar. I may be wrong. By the way, it is a good choice.

Comment: Sorry I don't know now to add new pics new here x

Comment: You could add new pictures by editing the original question -- immediately under the question there should be a link which says "edit".